# URLSession downloadTask w/ block get download progress

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

When I conform to the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`

The following delegate method can be used to get the progress of the download.

```
urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
           downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
           didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, 
           totalBytesWritten: Int64, 
           totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
```

But is it possible to get progress when using the completionHandler method?.

```
downloadTask(with request: URLRequest, 
             completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
```

Comment: I actually don't think this is possible Brandon. You may have to use the URLConnection delegate methods to achieve this.